# Stop Auto Submission of Form on KEYUP and make onSub() work when only onCheck() is Satisfied

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Here the below code will check for validation of email if the entered email is matched with the pattern it will show valid email address. I used **keyup() event** i know it will submit the form after matching with the pattern because i included **onSub()** in **onCheck()**. But what i want is **document.otp.submit()** has to work only when i click on the button but it has to work only when **onCheck()** is satisfied.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function onCheck() {
        var pattern = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
        var a=document.getElementById('email').value;
            if (pattern.test(a)) {
                document.getElementById('messages').style.color = 'green';
                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = "valid email id";
                onSub();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('messages').style.color = 'red';
                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = "invalid email id";
            } 
        }
    function onSub(){

        document.otp.submit();
    }
    </script>

    <body style="align:center">
<form name="otp" action="Otp" method="get">
    <label for="Email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onkeyup="onCheck()" placeholder="Enter Email.." ><span id='messages'></span><br><br>
        <button type='button' onclick="onSub()">Send OTP</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just for HTML correction: Put form tag in side body not body in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call onCheck() within onSub():

```js
function onCheck() {
  var pattern = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
  var a = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (pattern.test(a)) {
    document.getElementById('messages').style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = "valid email id";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('messages').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = "invalid email id";
    return false;
  }
}

function onSub() {
  if (onCheck())
    document.otp.submit();
}
```

```html
  <form name="otp" action="Otp" method="get">
    <label for="Email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" onkeyup="onCheck()" placeholder="Enter Email.."><span id='messages'></span><br><br>
    <button type='button' onclick="onSub()">Send OTP</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: i have a small doubt if i have more than 3 functions if i write like this   `function onSub() {
  if (onCheck()){
    if(check1())document.otp.submit();
}}` its working for two if conditions how to do if i have more than 3 functions help me with the logic

Comment: You don't need to create different functions, you can place all you checks in single function and return appropriate output(true/false)